# Generating XML feed from Components

Tags: xml

I have a Schema with some RTF fields in it. I need to provide a RSS feed for Components based on this Schema.

The problem is, the RTF fields contain some HTML markup and inline Component links (sometimes to multimedia Components - PDFs, images etc.). To satisfy the requirements I need to maintain these links in the RSS feed. Upon publishing I can see tags with `tridion:href` which are then resolved on the presentation side to regular links.

How do I parse/escape these links or any HTML content to make it XML compliant (replace `<` & `>` with `&lt;` & `&gt;` and similar)?

I am using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 and Java on the presentation side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escaping would be a way as [@user978511 suggests](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/generating-xml-feed-from-components/4153/#4153), but [RSS feeds](http://www.w3schools.com/rss/) are valid XML, so you can simply keep the `tridion:href` attribute in your links as long as you add the appropriate namespace to your XML.

The correct namespace for the `tridion` prefix would be `http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0`, you can add that to the `rss` root element of your feed XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:tridion="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
    ...
</rss>
```

### Update

You will need to adjust your Component/Page Template to keep the `tridion:href` attribute from being resolved. Most likely you currently have the **Default Finish Actions** Template Building Block in your Component Template, which contains the **Link Resolver** TBB, and that is responsible for resolving the link.

If you require a specific output, you have to create a custom Component Template (and possibly also a custom Page Template with that) to ensure you meet your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Bart, but the problem is the tridion:href attribute gets transformed into an actual HTML a:href after publishing which invalidates the XML.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to apply XSLT transformation to it. You can google a bit and find something like:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162352/converting-xml-to-escaped-text-in-xslt
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773334/html-escape-some-xml-tag-using-xslt

Just pick the most appropriate

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is there a way to do this without using XSLT?